# How to create box plot in google chart?

Tags: python, google-visualization

I would like to create a boxplot using google chart.

I tried to read `https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/compound_charts#box_charts` but I don't understand how to start.

How to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

The data are

3866.98
1340.74
2071.56
2574.31
2469.57
1988.61
959.35
1619.34
1246
1063.86
1412.08
1352.95
732.72
840.74
1190.32
919.03
1158.07
1222.56
1008.82
726.73
638.32
1341.12
1429.38
1797.39
3174.39
2737.36
2034.05
854.34
1719.09
1387
1206.4
1777.8
2170.07
1027.43
1141.08
1418.48
1325.99
967.99
1424.78
674.72
676.18
713.47

and

3678.25
3587.91
5872.75
6092.34
4673.97
3552.83
1950.46
4237.72
3370.54
2987.67
3312.55
3160.13
1671.61
2393.07
3287.01
2392.64
2599.15
2518.06
2215.14
1565.59
1700.56
3922.74
3280.04
3616.88
5386.46
4624.65
3515.98
1617.95
4628.09
3868.39
3231.57
3957.05
4577.2
1941.77
2256.69
3307.08
3418.41
2117.63
3105.99
1460.15
1582.4
1706.43

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far, and read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBoxPlot);

    function drawBoxPlot() {

      var array = [
data_here
      ];

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'x');
      column_here

      data.addColumn({id:'max', type:'number', role:'interval'});
      data.addColumn({id:'min', type:'number', role:'interval'});
      data.addColumn({id:'firstQuartile', type:'number', role:'interval'});
      data.addColumn({id:'median', type:'number', role:'interval'});
      data.addColumn({id:'thirdQuartile', type:'number', role:'interval'});

      data.addRows(getBoxPlotValues(array));

      /**
       * Takes an array of input data and returns an
       * array of the input data with the box plot
       * interval data appended to each row.
       */
      function getBoxPlotValues(array) {

        var c = array[0].length;

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

          var arr = array[i].slice(1).sort(function (a, b) {
            return a - b;
          });

          var max = arr[arr.length - 1];
          var min = arr[0];

          array[i][c] = max;
          array[i][c+1] = min
          array[i][c+2] = Quartile(arr, 0.25);//firstQuartile;
          array[i][c+3] = Quartile(arr, 0.5);//median;
          array[i][c+4] = Quartile(arr, 0.75);//thirdQuartile;
        }
        return array;
      }

          function Quartile(data, q) {
  data=Array_Sort_Numbers(data);
  var pos = ((data.length) - 1) * q;
  var base = Math.floor(pos);
  var rest = pos - base;
  if( (data[base+1]!==undefined) ) {
    return data[base] + rest * (data[base+1] - data[base]);
  } else {
    return data[base];
  }
}

function Array_Sort_Numbers(inputarray){
  return inputarray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
}



      var options = {
          title:'Box Plot',
          height: 500,
          legend: {position: 'none'},
          hAxis: {
            gridlines: {color: '#fff'}
          },
          lineWidth: 0,
          series: [{'color': '#D3362D'}],
          intervals: {
            barWidth: 1,
            boxWidth: 1,
            lineWidth: 2,
            style: 'boxes'
          },
          interval: {
            max: {
              style: 'bars',
              fillOpacity: 1,
              color: '#777'
            },
            min: {
              style: 'bars',
              fillOpacity: 1,
              color: '#777'
            }
          }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('box_plot'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

  </script>
```

Comment: Please give more explanation even though code is explanatory